# Joomla 3 template override - can't find the right file

Tags: joomla

I am creating a Joomla 3 template

I want to do a template override for the category blog layout.

However, I can't seem to find the file that I need to edit.
I found the one for a single article page:

com_content->views->article->tmpl->default.php

I was expecting something similar for the category-blog layout but I can't find it!

Does anyone know which file I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog.php
```

or another files in that folder.

Comment: thanks - I think I was still in the previous version of joomla mindset where I was looking for default.php